# Android: provider for Location object

Tags: android, location

What is the use of the provider parameter in Location constructor?

```
Location (String provider)
```

Can I pass other Strings than `NETWORK_PROVIDER` or `GPS_PROVIDER`?

The reason is I want to store in a data structure some coordinates, using a Location object instead of a pair of doubles. Is this a right reasoning?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Can I pass other Strings than NETWORK_PROVIDER or GPS_PROVIDER?

Yes you can.

There is a Passive Provider you can pass to Location.
Passive Provider:

A special location provider for receiving locations without actually initiating a location fix.

This provider can be used to passively receive location updates when other applications or services request them without actually requesting the locations yourself. This provider will return locations generated by other providers. You can query the getProvider() method to determine the origin of the location update.
hope this helps.

Comment: ¿? I answered first, your two questions, and Neurenor answered later only one question and you gave him the right answer???

Answer (score 0):

You can pass PASSIVE_PROVIDER too (search for documentation).

I would never store a Location object, I find no sense in that. Store a pair of doubles, please:-)